# Kotlin Retrofit upload file face Error Exception End of Input

Tags: kotlin, exception, file-upload, retrofit, multipart

I am new to Android app development. I am writing app to upload an image file (captured by camera app from previous activity) to the server, using Kotlin Retrofit Multipart. Camera App was working, as the image was stored in the folder. I just passed the stored file location URI to the uploadfile.kt activity to upload file to server.

However I encountered an error. Error was captured in the logcat, as shown below.

D  url location file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camera/Camera/23-07-10-01-10-13-520.jpg
D  Uploading image file
D  On upload progress 3
D  On upload progress 7
.....
D  On upload progress 100
D  Error Exception End of input

I could not figure up what went wrong.

Appreciate any help or advice on how to troubleshoot or resolve it?

Thank you for any help

Below is the code

**Code for Interface**

```
interface api {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/uploadfile.php")
    suspend fun uploadFile(
        @Part imagefile: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("itemid") itemid: Int
    ): Response<Apiresponse>

}
```

**Data Class for API Response**

```
data class Apiresponse(
    /**
     * Define data class from API response
     * status : ok or failed
     * resultcode: 0 (failed) or 1 (passed)
     */
    @Json(name = "status") val status: String,
    @Json(name = "result_code") val result_code: String
)
```

**Object for Retrofit**

```
object retrofit {

    // url of the server to upload image file
    val baseUrl = "https://xxxx.com/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    }
}
```

**Kotlin Class UploadStreamRequestBody
**

```
class UploadStreamRequestBody (
    private val mediaType: String,
    private val inputStream: InputStream,
    private val onUploadProgress: (Int) -> Unit,
) : RequestBody() {


    override fun contentLength(): Long = inputStream.available().toLong()

    override fun contentType(): MediaType? = MediaType.parse(mediaType)

    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        val contentLength = inputStream.available().toFloat()
        val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) // DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE constant from kotlin.io.ConstantsKt
        inputStream.use { inputStream ->
            var uploaded = 0
            var read: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) { // Reads the stream until the content ends
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read)
                uploaded += read
                onUploadProgress((100*uploaded/contentLength).toInt())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Uploadfile.kt Code**

```
class uploadfile : AppCompatActivity() {

    // create viewbinding to this ActivityUploadfile
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityUploadfileBinding

    private var imageUrl: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityUploadfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

      
        val tv_filelocation = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.location)

        // declare intent to receive parameter passed in
        val intent = getIntent()

        val itemid = 1

        // convert the image file location String to URI
        val imageUrl = Uri.parse(intent?.getStringExtra("imageuri"))
       
        // Display file location by converting URI to string value
        tv_filelocation.text = imageUrl.toString()

        Log.d("My Activity","url location "+imageUrl)
       

        // upload image file
        uploadFile(imageUrl)


    }

 // upload image file
    private fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return@launch
            val request = UploadStreamRequestBody("image/*", stream, onUploadProgress = {
                Log.d("MyActivity", "On upload progress $it")
                binding.progressBar.progress = it // Some ProgressBar
            })
            val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                "file",
                "test.jpg",
                request
            )
            try {
                //setup the API with Retrofit Moshi Converter
                val myapi = retrofit.getInstance().create(com.example.camera.api::class.java)

                Log.d("MyActivity", "Uploading image file")

                val responseresult = myapi.uploadFile(filePart, itemid =1)

                Log.d("MyActivity", "Download completed for image file")

               
            }
            catch(e: Exception) { // if something happens to the network
                Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Something went wrong", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Error Exception "+e.message)
                return@launch
            }
            Log.d("MyActivity", "On finish upload file")

        } // end lifecyclescope launch

    } // end upload file function



}
```

I placed some logging in the code, it seems that the program pop out error inside the myapi.uploadFile, and stopped there.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of what logcat is showing?

Comment: Only shows the following lines..."On upload progress (from 1 to 100)" ... the last line  and it stopped there is "Error Exception End of input "